# Are we doing anything differently with duplicates when there is no answer?

Tags: discussion

In review, I'm seeing a couple subtle changes. First, the wording on the first popup changed to 'This question has been asked before **and already has an answer**.'(emphasis mine)

[image: close dialogue 1]

The next dialogue is 'Where has this question been asked **and answered?**'

[image: close dialogue 2]

I never give any consideration to whether a duplicate had answers or not. It's either a duplicate question or it isn't. The closest thing to this issue is [this meta post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3792/flagging-duplicate-questions-when-answers-are-not-accepted) about dupes with no accepted answer.

Are we treating flagging, voting, or closing duplicates differently now? If no, why change the wording of the review guidance?

If I re-word my question a bit, '**Do we still close duplicates with no answer?**'

Comment: If we are, this is a message from the overlords. I'll search meta.

Comment: Nothing changed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133955/prevent-closing-as-duplicate-when-the-duplicate-has-no-accepted-answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do we still close duplicates with no answer?

#### Yes.

If both questions have no answers and one of them provides more detail, do allow some self judgement on which should be the dupe of what.

Comment: But "This question has been asked before and already has an answer" is still confusing even after @jrg's comments and your answer. I'm not sure that the meta.stackoverflow link explains the presence of (and need for) "and already has an answer".